# Bower link equivalent in composer - developing packages locally

Tags: php, composer-php, bower

I am develping few apps that have some common code. I want to create package for this common code with composer and develop it locally. I did the same with bower on the frontend. It's very easy when you want to develop the frontend package locally. I just used `bower link` and bower knows that he has to use local code instead of the one from repository. How to do the same with composer?